# CSS format special content in TextBox

Tags: html, css, textbox, format

I have a Textbox:
    
Now i want to highlight specific characters in this textbox with a colour. (for example "Text")
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Use ajax/jQuery for highlighting particular selected words in a textarea while writing words.

Check this link- http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/820173-highlighting-searched-word-text-area

Comment: could i do it with simple javascript?

Comment: Could you please explain it little bit @swapnesh

Comment: Yes, you can use javascript to do this. you can either call the function to check for an highlight words using the onblur, onkeydown, or onkeyup events in the textbox. You would want to get the value of the textbox using it's id in the javascript, like var text = document.getElementById('textbox_id').value; then perform your search and formatting based on that.

Comment: Check this link -http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/820173-highlighting-searched-word-text-area

Comment: Yes, u can use JS, check the above link

Comment: put this link in the answer as well

Comment: in this link it's explained how to put <span> tags around a specific text, but if i write this to the textbox, it won't be formated
it just looks like this "Example <span ...>Text</span>"

Answer (score 1):

There is another way without using Javascript to place a text on a textbox. But the text will be ash all the time. There is a tag name "placeholder" on HTML. That may help

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="text" name="inputbox">
```